# How to cast perforrmantly when dividing float and int?

Tags: casting, floating-point, kotlin, division

If I divide a float by an integer then I have two possibilities how to cast:

```
var f : Float
val i : Int = 2
f = 1f / i
```

Here I "cast" the first parameter by saying it is a float. Then if I correctly understand i is casted implicitly.

```
var f : Float
val i : Int = 2
f = 1 / i.toFloat()
```

Here I cast the second parameter to float. Then if I correctly understand the 1 is casted to float, too.

My Question is if the first of the two possibilities is faster. Or do I have the same performance in both cases?

Comment: Please also consider performance optimizations if you made sure that you need to make the application faster. In this case you won't notice the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the decompiled bytecode of the two snippets, with comments explaining the parts that are different between the two.

First version:

```
   L1
    LINENUMBER 16 L1
    ICONST_2
    ISTORE 1
   L2
    LINENUMBER 17 L2
    FCONST_1           // create constant float value 1f
    ILOAD 1            // load value of i
    I2F                // cast i from int to float
    FDIV               // perform division
    FSTORE 0           // write result to f
```

Second version:

```
   L1
    LINENUMBER 22 L1
    ICONST_2
    ISTORE 1
   L2
    LINENUMBER 23 L2
    ICONST_1           // create constant int value 1
    I2F                // cast this value from int to float
    ILOAD 1            // load value of i
    I2F                // cast i from int to float
    FDIV               // perform division
    FSTORE 0           // write result to f
```

Basically, you're saving an int to float cast in the first version, because you're creating a float constant `1f` immediately.

In reality though, this could be easily optimized by the JVM anyway, and is not worth worrying about at the syntax level - just use whichever code is more expressive for what you're doing. If you're somehow writing code that would benefit from performance improvements this tiny, do profiling on it to see if there's somehow a difference.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between your two snippets is syntax. There is no CPU out there that could natively perform a computation on one FP argument and one integer argument. Integer arguments are always first converted to FP.

If you're worried about the `.toFloat()` part, that's again just syntax. There is no actual method call going on, it just changes the type of the `Int` expression to `Float`.